# How do I make an editable ListView item?

Tags: listview, flutter, richeditabletext

I have dynamic data and I am using ListView.builder to show the user. I simply use a Text to show the data to user. Only right I add an edit icon so when user clicks the icon it enables user to edit specific Text. How do I make an editable ListView item?

Comment: Use TextField instead of Text Widget & pass Dynamic data as Initial data - then on edit enable that TextField & edit Text.

Comment: thanks, but TextField is editable anyway. when user clicks accidentally it can enter any text. I need to use clicks an icon to open a dialog end edit the text. then I can use setState to update the Listview item such as list tile subtitle.

Comment: TextField has enabled: Property you can disable it initially & then enable it on click of edit Icon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call the following class into itemBuilder: , filed of ListView.builder(...)

```
class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  bool _isEnabled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: TextField(
        enabled: _isEnabled,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Enter a text',
        ),
      ),

      // The icon button which will notify list item to change
      trailing: GestureDetector(
        child: new Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState((){
            _isEnabled = !_isEnabled;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I get it. I am using TextField controller as well so after user make changes I can update the DB. Now I have a problem to set edit icon on or off so user can get better visual what they can do with it. Thanks

Comment: @Nick I have the solution for your next problem :D
You can change icon dynamically
child: new Icon(
          _isEnabled ? Icons.edit : Icons.(use icon which you need),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),

Where the _isEnabled from previous answer

Answer (score 2):

You can make use the editable field of the TextField to make the TextField editable or not.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: List.generate(100, (index){
            return MyTile(index: index);  
          }),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  MyTile({Key key, this.index}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTileState createState() => _MyTileState();
}

// A custom list tile
class _MyTileState extends State<MyTile> {
  // Initalliy make the TextField uneditable.
  bool editable = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(           
              enabled: editable,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Index ${widget.index}",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)                
              ),
              onEditingComplete: (){
                // After editing is complete, make the editable false
                 setState(() {
                  editable = !editable;                
                });
              },
            ),
          ),

          RaisedButton(
            elevation: 1.0,
            child: Text('Edit'),
            onPressed: (){
              // When edit is pressed, make the editable true
              setState(() {
                editable = !editable;                
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Sagar, In my ListView I have only 8 items and only 3 items mus be editable. Alex suggestion its much easier to me. But I will keep your code in my future use. Thanks

Comment: Ok great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use textfield but it is very expensive in a medium scrollable table... unworkable....

The solution was using just Text to show fields and when in edit mode, I show a dialog or replace all Text by Textfield in that line...